# Is there a way to make an game available for only xbox series s/x and not for xbox one?

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, store

My game, built with Unity for UWP, I am using a library that is not supported for xbox one, when I upload the game I do not see a place to separate xbox one and xbox series,
what should i do ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.
There's a section in the developer portal for game asset definitions. You can specify which consoles are supported for your game.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/games/xbox/docs/xboxlive/asset-versions

Comment: i get this error , Sorry, we couldn't find that page.

Comment: https://ibb.co/kK3tLyk

Comment: i just have this in my developer account

Answer (score 0):

I have to say you can't specific device for the app such as only aviable for xbox series. As you know the store aviable options of the device family only contains Xbox option on the list when you publish your app. You can only detect current device info witin code behind and show dialog to notify the people xbox one is not aviaiable.